# Como crear un método getProductsbyId en firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, ionic

Estoy haciendo una aplicación movil con ionic y estoy usando firebase como bbdd. Necesito un método que me saque un producto por su id para poder mostrarlo en una ventana a parte.

Necesito uno que me pille un producto por su id para que me muestre unicamente ese producto en una pantalla a parte

Estos son los métodos que tengo:

```
    getItemById(id){

   
  }

  getCollectionChanges<tipo>(enlace:string): Observable<tipo[]> {
    const ref= this.angularFirestore.collection<tipo>(enlace);
    return ref.valueChanges();
  }

  getCollection<tipo>(path: string) {
    const collection = this.angularFirestore.collection<tipo>(path);
    return collection.valueChanges();
  }

  //Para pillar el ID
  getId(){
    return this.angularFirestore.createId();
  }
```